# Levantar ventana de recordatorio con swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, swift

se puede levantar al ventana del recordatorio del iPhone para configurar un nuevo recordatorio personalizado algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy tratando con

```
do {
        try appleEventStore.save(reminder, commit: true)
        print("Reminder added with dates:")
    } catch let e as NSError {
        print("Error al crear recodatorio: ", e.description)
        return
    }
```

pero solo crea el recordatorio con los parametros que le mando sin abrir la ventana para que el usuario lo personalice.

hay alguna forma de hacerlo, ayuda por favor.

Comment: OSEA LA IDEA ES ABRIR LA APP NATIVA DE RECORDATORIOS DESDE MI APP Y MANDARLES PARAMETROS BASICOS PARA QUE EL USUARIO PUEDA CREA R SU RECORDATORIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir los recordatorios desde tu app, necesitas la url que está asociada a esa app:

```
"x-apple-reminderkit://"
```

Quedaría así:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let url = URL(string: "x-apple-reminderkit://")//La url de la app
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:]) { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he leído que esa url no está documentada por lo tanto será rechazada por apple, es correcto?

Comment: El código no es ilegal ni malicioso. Para abrir otras aplicaciones la estructura es similar; pero siempre queda en esperar la respuesta de Apple cuando revise tu app. No creo que la rechacen.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGO